# Are there definition of percent?

Tags: notation, definition

In a school I was taught that percent is the same as 1/100. But I think that definition is not rigorous enough because that would imply for example that $5+4\%=5+4/100=5.04$ but this seems weird. So how one can define the percent rigorously?

Comment: I don't think the problem here is whether or not $1\%=1/100$, but rather what "$5+4\%$" means. Does it mean $5$ whole units plus $4\%$ of an unit, so $5.04$ as in 5xum's answer, or $5$ plus $4\%$ of $5$, which is $5.2$? In the second case, it could more accurately be written as $5\times104\%$. In practice, you will probably have to work out from context (or ask somebody) what is meant.

Comment: You answered your own question really. When you say "% is the same as 1/100" then from your example follows: 5 + 4% = 5 + 4*(1/100) = 5.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when we speak of something like $4\%$, the immediate question that should arise is

> "Four percent **of** what?"

- "of" usually translates to multiplication.

We can call that "what" $x$, for now.

So if we speak of $4\%$ of $x$, this is equivalent to $0.04\times x = \frac {4}{100}\times x$...

We rarely see $5 + 4\%$. It would be more likely we encounter $5 + 4\%$ of $x$.

For example, if we invest $\$5$, and we earn $4\%$ interest on our investment by year's end, we have $$5 + 4\%\times 5 = 5 + 0.04\times 5 = 5\times (1+0.04) = \$5.20$$ by years end, with a net earning of $\$.20$.

In your calculation, the only way to conclude that $5 + 4\% = 5.04$ is by making the assumption that $4\%$ means $4\%$ **of** $1$. It is very likely that what was intended was something along the lines of the example I give immediately above. Another example:

If we know only that we invested $x$ dollars, and learn that we earned a $4\%$ profit, what that means, implicitly is that we earned a profit of $4\%\times x = 0.04\times x$, where $x$ is the invested quantity.

Comment: Some calculators give `5+4%=5.20`, by the way. (Probably because those calculators are usually used in accounting and the like.)

Answer (score 1):

The definition is entirely correct. $1\% = \frac1{100}$.

This means that $5=500\%$, and $5 + 4\% = 500\% + 4\% = 504\% = 5.04$.

---

Usually, percents are used to denote the amount "of the whole" of something, so, for example, $4\%$ of one hundred dollars equals four dollars, and four percent of one dollar is four cents.

In your case, $5+4\%$ of something simply means taking $5$ whole parts of that something and adding another four percent of the same thing, so $(5+4\%)$ of one dollar is equal to $5$ dollars and $4$ cents.

Comment: Small glitch: that should be "504%" rather than "504\$".

Comment: Okay. It may sound weird to say e.g. "The multiplicative identity of a ring is $100\%$" but if it is correct then I just have to agree that it is fine but clumsy to say so.

Comment: @thinker Why would it be weird? Just think of $\%$ as a number, so $\%$ is just a symbol you use to denote $\frac1{100}$. Now, saying $100\%$ is the multiplicative identity of $\mathbb R$ is completely rational.

Comment: In some rings, it may not make sense to speak of percents since hundredths need not exist in all rings.